# Prevent session attribute access by EL

Tags: java, jsp, el

I understand how to access Session attributes using EL in my JSP/Servlet application:

```
    <p> Hello <c:out value="${sessionScope.userName}"/> </p>
```

However, I was wondering if there was a way to hide a Session variable from JSP page EL access? If I set a session variable in my servlet, such as:

```
    UserDAO user = new UserDAO();
    user.setUserName("XYZ");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
```

Is there a way to prevent that UserDAO Java Object's fields from being accessed on the JSP with some code such as:

```
    <p> Hello <c:out value="${user.userName}"/> </p>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't. At least, not without writing a custom EL resolver which isn't exactly trivial.

Your best bet is to wrap it in an object which does not expose the value by a Javabean getter method. E.g.

```
public class UserWrapper implements Serializable {

    private User user;

    public UserWrapper(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User get() {
        return user;
    }

}
```

Store it in the session as follows instead.

```
session.setAttribute("user", new UserWrapper(user));
```

Get it from the session as follows instead.

```
User user = ((UserWrapper) session.getAttribute("user")).get();
```

This method is inaccessible in EL. At least, in EL versions prior 2.2 where you could otherwise just do `#{user.get()}`.

Alternatives are to make the getter method of the wrapper class package-protected so that it's only accessible by classes in the same package and/or subclasses (EL namely requires it to be public).

```
    protected User get() {
        return user;
    }
```

Or even make the whole wrapper class a private or package-protected inner class.

Comment: So simple and right in front of my face. Thank you very much.  Using a Wrapper (Hider) class will be easy to implement too.

Comment: Just to update for anyone else with this issue, I implemented the UserWrapper Class as it's own serializable class, then made the User get() function a package-private method.  The wrapper class is then placed in the same package as my Authenticator class, thereby allowing any other class to set the User Object in the session, but only allowing the Authenticator class to un-wrap (access) the User object from the session. Thanks again BalusC